# Twitter Application-twitter4j

Tags: twitter4j

I am new to Twitter4j In my twitter application I want  to retweet the status But it shows the error as,

11-17 17:39:34.518: ERROR/TAG(470): 404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exists.

can anyone help me to retweet the status,I searched over Tags but not clear

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are specifying a non-existing status id.

Thanks